# Unity c sharp - changing the resolution aspect ratio according to screen size through code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, screen-resolution

Hello I want to resize the screen aspect ratio according to the screen size through code but I couldn't find a way to do that:

public class ResolutionFixer : MonoBehaviour
{

```
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    var res = Screen.currentResolution;
    float ratio = (float)res.width/res.height;
    print(ratio);
    //change the game's ratio aspect to the give ratio here

}
```

Note: tried using:

Screen.SetResolution(res.width, res.height, true);

but it didn't work

[image]

Comment: `tried using Screen.SetResolution(res.width, res.height, true);` ... well this is just using the original resolution the screen already had so what would you expect to happen?

Comment: res is the screen resolution, not the game's one, isn't it?

Comment: Oh now I see what you mean. This won't work in the Unity Editor .. there you can't resize the game view window by code afaik . Try simply enabling the `MaximizeOnPlay` at the top right of the game view

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/screen-setresolution-not-changing-resolution.654817/#post-4385497), I think you cannot emulate Screen.SetResolution() in Editor, Try building it and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Resizing the Game View through code is possible with some reflection.

This works for me:

```
using UnityEditor;
using System.Reflection;

public static class GameViewUtils {
    public enum GameViewSizeType {
        AspectRatio,
        FixedResolution
    }

    private static readonly object gameViewSizesInstance;
    private static readonly MethodInfo getGroup;

    static GameViewUtils() {
        var sizesType = typeof(Editor).Assembly.GetType("UnityEditor.GameViewSizes");
        var singleType = typeof(ScriptableSingleton<>).MakeGenericType(sizesType);
        var instanceProp = singleType.GetProperty("instance");
        getGroup = sizesType.GetMethod("GetGroup");
        gameViewSizesInstance = instanceProp.GetValue(null, null);
    }

    public static void AddCustomSize(GameViewSizeType viewSizeType, GameViewSizeGroupType sizeGroupType, int width, int height, string resolutionName) {
        var group = GetGroup(sizeGroupType);
        var addCustomSize = getGroup.ReturnType.GetMethod("AddCustomSize"); // or group.GetType().
        var assembly = Assembly.Load("UnityEditor.dll");
        var gameViewSize = assembly.GetType("UnityEditor.GameViewSize");
        var gameViewSizeType = assembly.GetType("UnityEditor.GameViewSizeType");
        var ctor = gameViewSize.GetConstructor(new [] {
            gameViewSizeType,
            typeof(int),
            typeof(int),
            typeof(string)
        });
        var newSize = ctor.Invoke(new object[] { (int)viewSizeType, width, height, resolutionName });
        addCustomSize.Invoke(group, new [] { newSize });
    }

    public static void SetSize(int index) {
        var gvWndType = typeof(Editor).Assembly.GetType("UnityEditor.GameView");
        var selectedSizeIndexProp = gvWndType.GetProperty("selectedSizeIndex",
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var gvWnd = EditorWindow.GetWindow(gvWndType);
        selectedSizeIndexProp.SetValue(gvWnd, index, null);
    }

    public static bool SizeExists(GameViewSizeGroupType sizeGroupType, string text) {
        return FindSize(sizeGroupType, text) != -1;
    }

    public static int FindSize(GameViewSizeGroupType sizeGroupType, string text) {
        // GameViewSizes group = gameViewSizesInstance.GetGroup(sizeGroupType);
        // string[] texts = group.GetDisplayTexts();
        // for loop...

        var group = GetGroup(sizeGroupType);
        var getDisplayTexts = group.GetType().GetMethod("GetDisplayTexts");
        var displayTexts = getDisplayTexts.Invoke(group, null) as string[];
        for(int i = 0; i < displayTexts.Length; i++) {
            string display = displayTexts[i];
            // the text we get is "Name (W:H)" if the size has a name, or just "W:H" e.g. 16:9
            // so if we're querying a custom size text we substring to only get the name
            // You could see the outputs by just logging
            // Debug.Log(display);
            int pren = display.IndexOf('(');
            if (pren != -1)
                display = display.Substring(0, pren - 1); // -1 to remove the space that's before the prens. This is very implementation-dependant
            if (display == text)
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static bool SizeExists(GameViewSizeGroupType sizeGroupType, int width, int height) {
        return FindSize(sizeGroupType, width, height) != -1;
    }

    public static int FindSize(GameViewSizeGroupType sizeGroupType, int width, int height) {
        // goal:
        // GameViewSizes group = gameViewSizesInstance.GetGroup(sizeGroupType);
        // int sizesCount = group.GetBuiltinCount() + group.GetCustomCount();
        // iterate through the sizes via group.GetGameViewSize(int index)

        var group = GetGroup(sizeGroupType);
        var groupType = group.GetType();
        var getBuiltinCount = groupType.GetMethod("GetBuiltinCount");
        var getCustomCount = groupType.GetMethod("GetCustomCount");
        int sizesCount = (int)getBuiltinCount.Invoke(group, null) + (int)getCustomCount.Invoke(group, null);
        var getGameViewSize = groupType.GetMethod("GetGameViewSize");
        var gvsType = getGameViewSize.ReturnType;
        var widthProp = gvsType.GetProperty("width");
        var heightProp = gvsType.GetProperty("height");
        var indexValue = new object[1];
        for(int i = 0; i < sizesCount; i++) {
            indexValue[0] = i;
            var size = getGameViewSize.Invoke(group, indexValue);
            int sizeWidth = (int)widthProp.GetValue(size, null);
            int sizeHeight = (int)heightProp.GetValue(size, null);
            if (sizeWidth == width && sizeHeight == height)
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private static object GetGroup(GameViewSizeGroupType type) {
        return getGroup.Invoke(gameViewSizesInstance, new object[] { (int)type });
    }
}
```

Based on the answers in this thread: http://answers.unity.com/answers/1791883/view.html